# Cannot find -ltensorflow

Tags: macos, go, tensorflow, clang

I'm trying to make work `TF` on `Mac OS X`. I ran the tutorial [how to install it.](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_go) All went well, the tensorflow library is install in my `GOPATH` but I keep getting this error.

```
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1
ld: library not found for -ltensorflow
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I understand it is something about `C` compiler cannot found `ltensorflow` library. `TF` runs all good with `Python2.7` though.

Any ideas how to fix it, please?

**EDIT**:

```
Air-MacBook-Air-Fonzik:GoTensor air$ echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/Users/air/PycharmProjects/GoTensor/
Air-MacBook-Air-Fonzik:GoTensor air$ echo $LIBRARY_PATH 
/Users/air/PycharmProjects/GoTensor/
Air-MacBook-Air-Fonzik:GoTensor air$ echo $GOPATH
/Users/air/PycharmProjects/GoTensor/
```

this is the output of my paths now, still does not work. The folder `GoTensor` contains the `pkg` and `src` of `tensorflow` go package. Is this setup correct?

Comment: Are you sure to have exported **both** `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:~/mydir/lib` and `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/mydir/lib` ? Because the error is pretty clear, it seems the linker can't find the library (thus `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` does not contain the path of the tensorflow lib)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `$LIBRARY_PATH` need to include the directory in which the C library (`libtensorflow.so`) is installed, not the Go libraries.

I suspect this is not the case for you
(`ls ${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}/libtensorflow.so`). (See Step 2 and 3 in https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_go).

To avoid needing the environment variables, you could also ensure that `libtensorflow.so` is in `/usr/local/lib` and then run `ldconfig` once after extracting it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: that did solve it, thanks! I added `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `$LIBRARY_PATH` to my `bash_profile` and works like a charm from terminal now. Not from PyCharm as editor, but I will figure that one out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good answer, I just want to add that detailed instructions on how to install tensorflow and configure the linker are provided here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c